# Conditional groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03','2015-01-03','2015-01- 02','2015-01-02','2015-01-01'],'myvals':[1,2,3,3,4,4,3]})
```

I want to count along with group by like:`df.groupby('dates')['myval'].transform('nunique')`

But I want to perform nunique with a condition only when `myval=3`

Desired Output:

```
dates        myvals
2015-01-01   1
2015-01-02   0
2015-01-03   2
2015-01-03   2
2015-01-02   0
2015-01-02   0
2015-01-01   1
```

How can I modify the code in that case.

Thanks!!

Comment: The way you explained if you only want to do nunique on myvals ==3 then the answer will always be 1 because there is only one group. What am i missing?

Comment: do you mean `df[df['my_val'].eq(3)].groupby('dates')['myval'].transform('nunique')` ?

Comment: `df.groupby('dates').myvals.transform(lambda x: len({*(x[x != 3])}))`?

Comment: I have added the desired output in the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['myvals'] = (df['myvals'] == 3).groupby(df['dates']).transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
        dates  myvals
0  2015-01-01     1.0
1  2015-01-02     0.0
2  2015-01-03     2.0
3  2015-01-03     2.0
4  2015-01-02     0.0
5  2015-01-02     0.0
6  2015-01-01     1.0
```